# The type or namespace name 'Resource File' does not exist in the namespace 'Resources' after deploying the Asp.Net app in Docker Kubernetes

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I have an ASP.NET Webforms application. It has been working without any issues for years. Now I am trying to deploy the app in Docker Kubernetes. It is deployed successfully without any compilation errors. But when I access one page it's throwing this exception:

> System.Web.HttpCompileException (0x80004005):
> c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Client\User\MyPage.aspx.cs(179): error
> CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Messages' does not exist in the
> namespace 'Resources' (are you missing an assembly reference?) at
> System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() at
> System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() at
> System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath
> virtualPath) at
> System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
> virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
> allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFoun d, Boolean
> ensureIsUpToDate)

Resource file `Messages.resx` is added in the `App_GlobalResources` folder and it's being copied under the root folder of the app as guided in the official documentation.

I have tried to recreate the resource also, but it also didn't work.

Below is the `Messages` class

```
#region Assembly App_GlobalResources.tlvvgtfn, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// C:\Users\Vivek.Nuna\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\dfad19b2\_shadow\477aa3de\26952\App_GlobalResources.tlvvgtfn.dll
#endregion

using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Resources;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Resources
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    [GeneratedCode("System.Resources.Tools.StronglyTypedResourceBuilder", "4.0.0.0")]
    public class Messages
    {
```

Comment: did you deploy your app to docker swarm or kubernetes? , and what kind of node are you using windows or linux? , can you also share your Dockerfile ?

Comment: @M__ I have solved the issues, Please find below my answer. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the issues. It copied to resource files with all lower cases in the file name. So I have made the changes in my Dockerfile to copy the file with the same cases in file names and it worked like magic.